# Print array values

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, printing

I have

```
$finalprint[$counting] = $ppn.' '.$ppn2;
```

By using loop i have saved some data into the array. Now have also done the sorting.

```
arsort($finalprint); // i think this would arrange the data into descending order by $counting
```

Now I have data's like

```
$finalprint[426] = "XYZ"
$finalprint[124] = "ABC"
$finalprint[333] = "MNO"
```

How i can print the values of this array, like `XYZ MNO ABC` ?

Comment: Are you trying to sort the array by descending order of the *keys / indexes*, e.g. 426, 333, 124, or by the *values*? If the array looked like `array( 333 => "XYZ", 426 => "ABC", 124 => "MNO" )`, what order would you want the elements printed in?

Comment: It has to be according numeric values.... so i want descending, it will be `ABC` `XYZ` `MNO` according to the array provided by you. According to mine it has to be `XYZ` `MNO` `ABC`

Comment: @JMM And if these are called `keys / indexes, e.g. 426, 333, 124` then definitely yes, i am asking to sort according to them only.

Comment: Ok, your question was confusing because in the example data you used, sorting by descending order of either the keys / numeric indices (that's what the 426, 333, 124 are called) OR the values would result in the same order. I updated my answer based on what you're really trying to do. For what it's worth, @Jocelyn mentioned `krsort()` earlier.

Comment: @GoldenHeat your edit krsort()($finalprint) is incorrect you have to pass the variable to the function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you want to sort according to **values** in desc order

```
$finalprint[] = "XYZ";
$finalprint[] = "ABC";
$finalprint[] = "MNO";

rsort($finalprint);

foreach ($finalprint as $val) {
    echo  $val."&nbsp;" ;
}
```

*o/p* XYZ MNO ABC

if you want to sort according to **keys** in desc order

```
krsort($finalprint);

foreach ($finalprint as $val) {
        echo  $val."&nbsp;" ;
    }
```

*o/p*  MNO ABC XYZ

Answer (score 0):

```
krsort( $finalprint );

echo join( " ", $finalprint );
```

But are you saying the array is sorted into `XYZ`, `ABC`, `MNO` order, or `XYZ`, `MNO`, `ABC` order?

Comment: It has to be in `XYZ` `MNO` `ABC` order

Comment: but after doing this, its showing me wrong order, now i am able to print but unable to sort. is this funtion is ok `arsort($finalprint);`

Comment: It should be. I think your values are maybe different than what you've used for examples here though. E.g., your first shippet of code inicates that your actual values include spaces, for example. Do `var_export( $finalprint )` on an array containing a few elements of your actual data, and update your question to include the output so we can see what you're working with.

Answer (score 0):

```
join(' ', array_values($finalprint));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [arsort](http://php.net/arsort) to sort the values in reverse order or [krsort](http://php.net/arsort) to sort the keys in reverse order. (It is not clear from your example which one you want)

```
arsort($finalprint);
echo implode(' ', $finalprint);
```

Documentation : [implode](http://php.net/implode)

Comment: `arsort()` sorts the array values (and maintains the keys). `explode()` is for turning a string into an array.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to print the contents in your requested order, try ordering the array values. `array_reverse` helps:

```
$finalprint = array();
$finalprint[426] = "XYZ";
$finalprint[124] = "ABC";
$finalprint[333] = "MNO";
//sort by key ascending
asort($finalprint);
//getting the keys and reversinf them
$keys = array_reverse(array_keys($finalprint));
//iterating over the keys
foreach ($keys as $key) {
    echo $key.'=>'.$finalprint[$key].PHP_EOL;
}
```