# Get array attribute in php if the value is yes

Tags: php, arrays

I just print_r my array:

```
Array ( [spec1] => yes [spec2] => yes [spec3] => yes [spec4] => yes )
```

I want to write an if statement if the spec value is "yes" to do something.

Like

```
if(spec1 == true) {
//do something
}
if(spec2 == true) {
//do something
}
```

Comment: simply write foreach loop and compare with key value

Comment: just iterate over your array and check the value using if condition

Comment: `"yes" !== true`

Comment: Actually, it is due to type casting. I would honestly suggest you change the `yes` to `true` or change the if to check if the value is `yes`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Print array values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11950704/print-array-values)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if($array['spec1'] == 'yes'){
    //do something
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can access the fields of an array using square brackets and the key you want to access.

```
$arr = array( 'spec1' => 'yes' ,'spec2' => 'yes', 'spec3' => 'yes', 'spec4' => 'yes' );

if($arr['spec1'] == 'yes') {
    //do something
}
if($arr['spec2'] == 'yes') {
    //do something
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's simple: access the array key using the squared brackets:

```
if($arrayName['spec1'] == true) ...
```

See [Accessing array elements with square bracket syntax](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php)

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach($myArray as $key => $value){
    if($value == true)
        //do something
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`array_walk` (http://php.net/array_walk) will loop through each entry in your array

```
$array = [
    'spec1' => 'yes',
    'spec2' => 'yes',
    'spec3' => 'yes',
    'spec4' => 'yes',
];
array_walk($array, function($value, $key) {
    if (strcasecmp($value, 'yes') === 0) { // case-insensitive comparison
        // do something...
        // Note: $key is available to the function if you need it
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add this code

```
$array = array(
    'spec1' => 'yes',
    'spec2' => 'yes',
    'spec3' => 'yes',
    'spec4' => 'yes'
);
foreach($array as $row){
    if($row=='yes') //do somthing.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should try below code.

```
<?php
foreach($your_array as $key => $value){
    if($value == 'yes'){
        //do something
    }
}
?>
```